# RichTextBox no reconoce su propio cambio de fuente

Tags: c#

tengo un problema y realmente no entiendo lo que sucede...
mi programa es para hacer plantillas y está en pleno desarrollo básico, omití muchas cosas, para poder mostrar el error y que ustedes me den la posible solución...
mientras el usuario confecciona la plantilla este puede insertar datos de 2 formas (son obligatorias), una es insertando confeccionando el dato (en la parte derecha del formulario) y la otra es por si la plantilla es muy larga el usuario puede escribirla todo y luego marcar lo que es dato y establecerlo como tal. Para que el usuario sepa que es dato y que es texto, estableci dos fuentes FDato(estilo gruesa y azul) y FTexto(estilo regular y negro), luego tengo un label que me dice exactamente si donde tengo el cursor del RichTextBox es dato o es texto. La sorpresa esta en que cuando lo inserto usando el segundo método, me dibuja el dato como tal, pero al poner el cursor me dice que es texto, sin embargo ese mismo dato ya cargado lo inserto mediante el primer método si lo hace correctamente.
Nota importante y de ultimo momento: Esta dirigido al framework 4.0. y lo curioso es que lo corri en linux con mono y que creen funcionó como yo deseo (solo ejecute el mismo .exe que compile en windows 10).

-Este es un gif donde muestra cual es el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
-codigo a continuacion

```
int posLine = 0;
    int posCol = 0;
    int totChL = 0;

    Font FTexto = new Font("Consolas", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font FDato = new Font("Consolas", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    void MostrarPos()
    {
        var a = richTextBox1.TextLength;
        var b = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        var c = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(b);
        var d = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var e = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(a);
        int f = richTextBox1.Text != "" ? richTextBox1.Lines[c].Length : 0;

        //totLine = e + 1;
        //totCol = a - e;
        totChL = f;
        posLine = c;
        posCol = d - c;
      
        label2.Text = string.Format("Linea:{0} Columna:{1} Caracteres por Linea:{2}", posLine, posCol, totChL);

        if (Font.Equals(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FDato))
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            label1.Text = string.Format("es DATO");
        }
        else
        {
            button2.Enabled = listBox1.Items.Count > 0;
            label1.Text = string.Format("es TEXTO");
            imADato.Enabled = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Agregar dato
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(textBox1.Text) < 0)
        {
            listBox1.Enabled = true;
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}|{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));

            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }

        if (!(richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0))
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            Button2_Click(sender, e);
            richTextBox1.HideSelection = true;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insertar dato
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int idValor = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf("|") + 1;
        string dato = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string valor = dato.Substring(idValor, dato.Length - idValor);

        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = FDato;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        Clipboard.SetText(valor);
        richTextBox1.Paste();
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = FTexto;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" ? true : false;
    }

    private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" ? true : false;
    }

    private void ImADato_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText;
        richTextBox1.HideSelection = false;
        textBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void RichTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MostrarPos();
    }

    private void RichTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MostrarPos();
    }
```